# Capture command output for n seconds, then detach it (run in the background)

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, background-process

I need to run a certain command (ngrok in this case) for a few seconds, capture all the output, filter out some variables and then detach the process, making it run invisibly in the background.
How can I do that?

Comment: capture the output where? In a file, shell variable?

Comment: file, variable, doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(cmd &) | (timeout --foreground 2 cat; cat > /dev/null &)
```

Would show you the output of `cmd` for 2 seconds and then return, with `cmd` running in background with its output going to `/dev/null`.

You can redirect that to a file or store in a variable with:

```
var=$(that command)
```

Comment: ngrok output can't unfortunately get captured like this, because it's sort of like **apt** output line updating, which doesn't get captured in a file. So this solution doesn't output anything. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I was able to make it work using this solution when I disabled the buffering via the expect's unbuffer. Thanks!

Comment: @freemanovec, you may try to use `stdbuf -o0` before `unbuffer` if available as `unbuffer` has a few issues.